If $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ is monotone, then $(\root{n}\of a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges?

Let $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ be a bounded monotone sequence of positive reals. Must $(\root n \of a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converge?

In any case where $\inf \{ a_n \mid n\in \mathbb{N}\}>0$, we can use the squeeze theorem to conclude that $(\root n \of a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ converges to $1$. When only given $\lim a_n = 0$, we cannot conclude convergence of $(\root n \of a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$, as in the case of $a_n=1/2^n$ for even $n$ and $a_n=1/3^n$ for odd $n$. Of course, this is sequence is not monotone. But I could not find a similar example for a monotone sequence.

If $0<\lim_na_n=L<\infty$ then thiis is true as $\lim_n\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=1$ and the  relation between limits of $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ and $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.

When $a_n\nearrow\infty$, then it could be that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ diverges to $\infty$: $a_n=n!$.

$a_n\searrow0$ does not mean that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ converges to $0$.

@psl2Z: of course, otherwise the whole this is trivial since your assumption of monotonicity. In any event, this is a summary of what I wrote: $\limsup_na_n\leq 1$. I was suggesting to look at a sequence where terms are repeated (to preserve monotonicity and to slow decay); for example, $1,\frac12,\frac12,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\frac14,\ldots$ where $\frac{1}{2^n}$ is repeated say $2^n^ times or something along those lines.

You can change your example to make it monotone. Essentially, you had two subsequences (one with "smaller" values and one with "larger" values) that you weaved together to make it not converge. To manipulate this into a monotone example, make the sequence constant for long stretches, until the "larger" subsequence has caught up.
More concretely, have $a_1=\frac13, a_2=\frac14, a_3=\frac1{27}$ as before. But now let $a_4, a_5$ also be $\frac1{27}$, so that $a_6=\frac1{64}$ doesn't break monotonicity. Then you can have $a_7=a_8=a_9=a_{10}=a_{11}=\frac1{2187}$ before you once again go back to the "even" subsequence with $a_{12}=\frac1{4096}$.
Continue this, and you will get your example sequence. If you want a strictly monotone sequence instead, it's not difficult to take all the constant denominators and tweak them slightly so that they increase strictly, for instance we could have $a_7=\frac1{2187}, a_8=\frac1{2188}$, and so on.

I want to ask a question: For such a strictly monotone sequence ${a_n}$, how to prove  the sequence ${\sqrt[n]{a_n}}$ is divergent in a cheapest way! Thank you!

@Riemann You still have infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n=\frac1{2^n}$ and infinitely many $n$ for which $a_n=\frac1{3^n}$. It's not trivial to describe exactly when they happen, but they happen. And for those terms, we have that $\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ is $\frac12$ or $\frac13$ respectively. A sequence that is infinitely many times $\frac12$ and infinitely many times $\frac13$ cannot converge.

This is a somewhat general method to generate a strictly positive monotone nonincreasing sequence $a_n\searrow0$ such that $\liminf_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}$.
Take for example $x_n=\alpha^n$ and $y_n=\beta^{n}$ where $0<\beta<\alpha<1$. For some monotone increasing sequence $m:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ to be determined define
\begin{align}
a_{m_k}=\alpha^{m_k},\
\qquad a_{m_k+j}=\beta^{m_k+1}\quad \text{for}\quad1\leq j< m_{k+1}-m_k
\end{align}
To make $a_n$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$, as intended it is enough to choose $m_k$ so that $m_1=1$ and
$$\beta^{m_k+1}>\alpha^{m_{k+1}}$$
or equivalently, that
$$\frac{m_{k+1}}{m_k+1}>\frac{\log(1/\beta)}{\log(1/\alpha)}$$
This method  can be applied to other sequences $0<y_n<x_n\searrow0$ where the rate of decay (to $0$) is known.
For example $x_n=\frac1n$ and $y_n=2^{-n}$. For a monotone increasing sequence $m:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$  with $m_1=1$ define
\begin{align}
a_{m_k}=\frac{1}{m_k},\qquad a_{m_k+j}=2^{-(m_k+1)} \quad\text{for}\quad 1\leq j<m_{k+1}-m_k
\end{align}
To obtain a monotone nonincreasing sequence $a_n$ it is enough to take
$$\frac1{2^{m_k+1}}>\frac1{m_{k+1}}$$
or equivalently
$$m_{k+1}>2^{m_k+1}$$

$\liminf_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\liminf_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ should be $\liminf_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}<\limsup_n\sqrt[n]{a_n}$??

If take $\alpha=\frac12$ and $\beta=\frac14$, can you make clear for $m:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$.

@Riemann: You may take $m_1=1$, and $m_{k+1}=3(m_k+1)$ since $\log(4)/\log(2)=2$.

@ Mittens OK , thanks for your comment, I will have a try!

Based on the idea of @Mittens and sequences $\{1/2^n\},\{1/4^n\}$,
we give a concrete example of sequence $\{a_n\}$ which is strictly decreasing such that $\lim\limits_{n\to}a_n=0$ but $\lim\limits_{n\to}\sqrt[n]{a_n}$ does't exist.
Set
$$n_1=1,\quad n_{k+1}=3(n_k+1),$$
which has the formula
$$n_k=\frac56\cdot 3^k-\frac32,\quad k\in\mathbb N^+.$$
For $k=1,2,3,\cdots,$ let
$$a_{n_k}=\left(\frac12\right)^{n_k},\quad
a_{n_k+j}=\left(\frac1{4+\frac{j}{n_{k+1}}}\right)^{n_k+1},j=1,2,\cdots,n_{k+1}-n_k-1,$$
obviously, $a_{n_k+i}>a_{n_k+j}$ for $1\leq i<j\leq n_{k+1}-n_k-1$,
we also have that:
$$a_{n_k}=\left(\frac12\right)^{n_k}>\left(\frac14\right)^{n_k}
>\left(\frac14\right)^{n_k+1}
>\left(\frac1{4+\frac{1}{n_{k+1}}}\right)^{n_k+1}
=a_{n_k+1},$$
and
$$a_{n_{k+1}-1}=\left(\frac1{4+\frac{n_{k+1}-n_k-1}{n_{k+1}}}\right)^{n_k+1}>\left(\frac18\right)^{n_k+1}
=\left(\frac12\right)^{3(n_k+1)}
=\left(\frac12\right)^{n_{k+1}}=a_{n_{k+1}}.$$
Hence the sequence $\{a_n\}$ is strictly decreasing and $\lim\limits_{n\to}a_n=0$.
It has two subsequences $\{a_{n_k}\}$ and $\{a_{n_k+1}\}$ satisfying
$$\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k]{a_{n_k}}=\frac12>\frac14
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\frac1{4+\frac{1}{n_{k+1}}}
=\lim_{k\to\infty}\sqrt[n_k+1]{a_{n_k+1}}.$$
